# Reference to drawn text using drawText() on a canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a canvas on which I have drawn some text using **drawText()**, is it possible to get a reference to that text? I want to select that text using the **onLongPress()** gesture and I think I need to have the reference of that text to do that.

Comment: this link can help you https://guides.codepath.com/android/Basic-Painting-with-Views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be having refrence to what you drawn using `drawText()` on canvas.To implement select text you have to use `Paint.measureText()` to get height and width of your text and then draw the backgound to make a custom effect of text selection(handle long press using `onTouch()`).

When drawing text on canvas you have to handle every behaviours of text view as your own.

An alternate way is to to Create a `TextView` and add it to any layout and then use the following code to draw the layout into canvas

```
//measure the width and height of the layout(covers entire canvas)
vLayout.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
//set the bounds of the layout.
vLayout.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
vLayout.draw(canvas);
```